# Laravel relationship return null

Tags: php, laravel

I have a store that is using a payment package
Now I want to show the items that were purchased, but I run into this problem

[image]

##### Controller

```
public function mycourse()
{
    $courses = PurchasedCourse::where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->with('course')
        ->get();
    dd($courses);
 
    return view('student.courses.mycourse', [
        'courses' => $courses
    ]);
}
```

##### Model

```
public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class, 'id');
}
```

##### Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('start');
        $table->string('end');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->string('jalasat');
        $table->string('zarfiat');
        $table->text('tozih');
        $table->integer('hit');
        $table->string('department');
        $table->string('thumbnail');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(0);
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: your `course` relationship is incorrect on the `PurchasedCourse` model. Please go through https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relationship method is wrong. The syntax for the `belongsTo()` method is

`belongsTo(class, ?foreign_id, ?related_id)`. In your case, it should be:

```php
public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class, 'course_id', 'id');
}
```

or just

```php
public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}
```

since your columns follow Laravel's naming conventions.